# How to insert a new record in an associated belongsTo table instead of editing the associated one

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In a edit-template, I created 2 forms. The first to edit a record from 'Table1' and a second form to add an record to the associated (belongsTo) table 'Table2'. I don't want to edit the associated record but add a new one in Table2 and change the bindingkey of the record from 'Table1'.

In the controller I use patchEntity(), but this way the original linked record in 'Table2' is edited.

The code for the second form look like this.

```
    <?= $this->Form->create($machine, ['url' => ['action' => 'edit_foto']]);?>
    <?= $this->Form->controls([
            'id' => ['type' => 'hidden'],
            'foto.omschrijving' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => __('naam van de machine'),
                'value' => $result->type_machine
            ], []);?>

    <?= $this->Form->button(__('save'), ['type' => 'submit']); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

In the controller for 'Table1' I use something like this.

```
public function editFoto($id) {

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getData();
    $machine = $this->Machines->get($id, [
        'contain' => [
            'Foto'
        ]
    ]);

    if ($this->request->is([
                'patch',
                'post',
                'put'
            ])) {

        $machine = $this->Machines->patchEntity($machine, $data);
        if ($this->Machines->save($machine)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Machine {naam} has been saved.', [
                'naam' => $machine['naam']
            ]));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit', $id]);
        }
    }

}
```

How can I prevent the controller from editing the original record and instead force to add a new record in 'Table2' and change the bindingkey in 'Table1'?

Help is much appreciated.

**added information:**
the data send by the form looks like:

```
[
    'id' => '87',
    'foto' => [
        'omschrijving' => 'WAKER 135 - ter - testje',
        'foto' => [
            'tmp_name' => 'C:\xampp\tmp\php6CFD.tmp',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'name' => 'MAKITA DTD153RTJ accuschroevendraaier.jpg',
            'type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'size' => (int) 188971
        ],
        'dir_id' => '5c9dd428cc4ef'
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$machine = $this->Machines->patchEntity($machine, $data);
$this->Machines->save($machine);
```

you should use

```
$machine = $this->Machines->newEntity($data, [
  'associated' => ['Fotos']
]);
$this->Machines->save($machine);
```

to save the data. If the associations between `Table1` and `Table2` are correct in the models, this will also update the binding keys.

Make sure, the format of the ids in FormHelper is correct. See the docs, how to handle [Saving With Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations). You can see this in `$data`. When submitting the form, `$data` should be in the following format:

```
$data = [
  'id' => '...',
  'foto' => [
    // ... model data
  ],
];
```

Comment: Then i get an error: "Argument 1 passed to Cake\ORM\Marshaller::one() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\myKMG\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table.php on line 2631 and defined [CORE\src\ORM\Marshaller.php, line 168]"

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe you used `$machine` instead of `$data` as a parameter?

Comment: Tanx, $data is saved as a new record, but the binding_key hasn't changed. Here is my code in the model: " $this->belongsTo('Foto', [ 'className' => 'Fotos', foreignKey' => 'foto_id' ]);", if it can help you out.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can use the `associated` parameter when creating an entity. In addition, please check the format of `$data`. The method `save()` will handle associations automatically if the format is correct.

Comment: With or without the associated parameter, it does the same.
When I debug both saved values `$machines->foto->id` and `$machines->foto_id`, I get the correct new value. 
It looks like the data in the redirected action isn't updated.
After a successfull saving, it should redirect to the main form1 (action = edit), and reload the changed record (machine) with the new foto, shouldn't it?

Comment: But the data is saved correctly into the database tables? If the data is in the database, it should read the new data after the redirect. Maybe there is some cache that stores the data of the previous request?

Comment: I don't know. How can I check it?